# How to continue loop java

Tags: java, loops

my program won't do what I need it to do and I have been stuck on this issue for six hours. It prompts the user to enter how many times they would like to toss a coin, the program counts how many heads and tails were tossed and spits out the total heads and tails as well as the percentage that were rolled as heads. my issue is that the loop just ends once it goes through for the first time. it just stops and wont prompt the user to select another number or to press 0 to quit the program and return to the main menu, how can I fix this? Also how can I have the option to return to another loop. I've tried the break method and it doesn't work for me. I don't know I am really lost. How can I make it so this loop continues to toss the coin and still ask the users how many times they want to toss it? While at the same time allowing them to simply press 0 and exit this loop to return to the main menu? I didn't post that code here but it's a while loop with different sub options/games.

```
if (anotherScanner.hasNext("t|T")) {

    c = anotherScanner.next();
    usersSelection = true;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("COIN TOSS SIMULATOR");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit. How many tosses?");

    Random rand = new Random();
    float headsCount = 0;
    float tailsCount = 0;
    Scanner scanMan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero = scanMan.nextInt();
    boolean headsOrTails;

    for (int j=0;j < numero;j++) {
        if (numero == 0) { break; }
        headsOrTails = rand.nextBoolean();

        if (headsOrTails == true) {
            headsCount++;
        } else {
            tailsCount++;               

            System.out.println(headsCount + " heads and " + tailsCount + " tails means " + (headsCount/(headsCount+tailsCount)*100 + "% were heads"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user input code needs to be in the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("\ncontinue to inner when i is 2 and j is 2:");
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    here4: for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        if ((i == 2) && (j == 2)) {
            System.out.print("[continue to inner]");
            continue here4;
        }
        System.out.print("[i:" + i + ",j:" + j + "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a loop to englobe your code: while(c != 0)

Comment: That answer is a bit short. You could write it a bit more specific and maybe show where to add that while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code intends to always enter the "for" loop, then if `numero == 0`, leaves the loop.

```
 for (int j = 0; j < numero; j++) {
    if (numero == 0) {
        break;
    }
    ...
 }
```

However, if numero == 0, the condition of the `for` -- `j < numero` is false, so the execution does not enter the for loop at all. So that `break` will never run.

You probably wanted something more like:

```
if(numero !=0) {
   for (int j = 0; j < numero; j++) {
      ...
   }
}
```

... although as written here, the `if` is irrelevant, because with `numero==0` the `for` loop still iterates zero times.

However your println() is inside the loop - it executes every time "tails" is tossed. I imagine you really wanted the println() to happen once, after all the coins have been tossed:

```
if(numero !=0) {
   for (int j = 0; j < numero; j++) {
      ...
   }
   System.out.println(...);
}
```

You will find that your code becomes a lot clearer if you break it down into more methods. Instead of putting your coin tossing loop in an `if` statement (this is called *inline*), put it in a method of its own, and put a call to the method in the `for` loop. So you end up with code like this:

```
// Get input; play game until input is zero.
void playCoinTossGames(Scanner scanner) {
   int input = promptAndGetInt(scanner);
   while(input != 0) {
      playOneCointossGame(input);
      int input = promptAndGetInt(scanner);
   }
  // note two calls to get input above. This is called a
  // "read-before-read-while" loop
}

// Print a prompt, then scan input for an integer
int promptAndGetInt(Scanner scanner) {
   System.out.println("How many tosses? (0 to exit)";
   return scanner.nextInt();
}

// Toss numberOfTosses times, then report the % of heads.
void playOneCointossGame(int numberOfTosses) {
   for(int i=0; i<numberOfTosses; i++) {
       // Toss a coin and record result
   }
   System.out.println(...); // summary of results
}
```